# How to fetch the specific data from the firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the specific data from the `firebase` into the android app.

I want to be fetch only that data `where ar="Atif Aslam"`. How I can do that? 
This is my database

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?Using query you can achieve this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#equalTo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: you want to fetch that node only where ar = "Atif Aslam"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");    
Query query
    =  mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("ar").equalTo("Atif Aslam");
```

refer examples from firebase official site:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using firebase.database.Query

```
Query msgQuery = childRef.orderByChild("ar").equalTo("Atif Aslam");
msgQuery.addChildEventListener(MainActivity.this);
```